# Polymorphic static const member variables in an ABC?

Tags: c++, static, polymorphism, constants

I have a rather strange situation where I would like to be able to define certain constants that a subclass of an ABC can override.

```
struct A {
    static const int a = 20;
    virtual int func() = 0;
};
struct B : public A {
    static const int a = 3;
    int func() { return 5; }
};
struct C : public A {
    static const int a = 4;
    int func() { return 3; }
};
```

Unfortunately, if I use `A *aPtr = new B`, `aPtr->a` will return 20, instead of 3.

One workaround I see is one-liner functions (along the lines of `func` in the above example), but the syntax of constants is quite a bit more appropriate for this particularly situation conceptually. Is there a syntactically reasonable way of resolving which constants to use at runtime, where the calling code doesn't need to know anything after initial object creation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding static variables when subclassing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594730/overriding-static-variables-when-subclassing)

Comment: The reasoning behind wanting this may be flawed: A constant is supposed to be, well, *constant*. It's not sometimes constant and sometimes something else. Similarly, static members are properties of classes, not instances, so they play no role in inheritance, which is an *instance*-based concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constants, especially static constants, cannot be overriden like you are asking for.  You would have to use a virtual function instead:

```
struct A {
    virtual int get_a() { return 20; }
    int func() = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    virtual int get_a() { return 3; }
    int func() { return 5; }
};

struct C : public A {
    virtual int get_a() { return 4; }
    int func() { return 3; }
};
```

Another option would be to use a template for the constant instead:

```
template< const int a_value = 20 >
struct A {
    static const int a = a_value;
    int func() = 0;
};

struct B : public A<3> {
    int func() { return 5; }
};

struct C : public A<4> {
    int func() { return 3; }
};
```

Comment: For the templated version one should note that the classes `B` and `C` are now entirely unrelated, since they have different base classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can get answer from the example itself ! :) Just declare a method like `get_a()` which is `virtual` and override the same.

```
struct A {
    static const int a = 20;
    virtual int get_a() const { return a; }  // <--- for A
};
struct B : public A {
    static const int a = 3;
    virtual int get_a() const { return a; }    // <--- for B
};
struct C : public A {
    static const int a = 4;
    virtual int get_a() const { return a; }    // <--- for C
};
```

Also note that, only method can be overridden in C++ and not the variables.