# Using inheritance with static function

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I want to design a parent class

```
//Parent.h
class Parent {
private:
   int currentId;
   static int getIdSquare(); //Just random function for simplicity
}
//Parent.cpp
#include "Parent.h"
int Parent::getIdSquare() { return this->currentId * this->currentId };
```

Of course this won't work! because you cannot access non-static variable in static function but hold on.
I want my child class to be like this

```
//Child.h
#include "Parent.h"
class Child : public Parent {
private:
    static int index;
};
//Child.cpp
#include "Child.h"
int Child::index = 5;
```

So that in main when I call `Child::getIdSquare();` I will get 25. And I should not be able to call `Parent::getIdSquare()` because its private. How do I go on about creating something like. This is a non-working code just to illustrate the concept. So if I make another child class i can specified the index in its own body. I want to call the method statically.

Please help me figure out this puzzle!

Comment: Is this the same question as your earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872126/c-inheritance-with-parent-knowing-the-children)? It's very similar.

Comment: How are `Child::index` and `Parent::currentId` related? Should the assignment to index set the value in the currentId value in the parent class?

Comment: Your problem isn't virtual functions or inheritance, it's a misunderstanding of `static`. `static` functions don't have any concept of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are after is really a `virtual static` function.  Unfortunately, that doesn't exist in C++.

Also, `Child::getIdSquare()` will also be private, and inaccessible in main().

If you need to *statically* pass a value from a child class to its parent, you may need to do it during the inheritance itself via a template argument.

```
template <int id>
class Parent
{
public:
    static int getIdSquare() { return id * id; }
}

class Child : public Parent<5>
{
}
```

Then `Child::getIdSquare()` will return 25, as required.  It doesn't get around the fact that you want `Parent::getIdSquare` to be private, while making it public in `Child` though.  For that you would need to declare it as private in `Parent` and then declare it *again* as public in `Child`, with an implementation of `return Parent<5>::getIdSquare();`

Still not ideal, but it's a relatively vague question, so hard to really find a perfect solution here...

Comment: Note that in this case each child has a different parent class, since each template instantiation creates a new type

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand the question, but I see two alternatives. If you want to implement type-specific properties you could go with traits:

```
template<typename T>
struct Square {};

class Parent {

};

class Child: public Parent {};

template<> Square<Parent> {

};

template<> Square<Child> {
     static constexpr int getIdSquare() {
         return 25;
     }
};

void foo() {
    // this will not compile
    //auto id = Square<Parent>::getIdSquare();

    // but this will
    auto id = Square<Child>::getIdSquare();
}
```

An alternative design would be to use the template method pattern, but this uses dynamic dispatch. It would look like this:

```
class Parent {
public:
     int getSquareId() {
         return currentId() * currentId();
     }
private:
     virtual int currentId() = 0;
};

class Child: public Parent {
private:
     virtual int currentId() override {
         return 5;
     }
};
```