# I'm learning the Curiously recurring template pattern. What's wrong with this template?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796580/static-variable-for-each-derived-class), I'm trying to learning [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

[This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/267f9771385752d2) is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class EnvelopeType>
class Envelope
{
public:
    double mSingle = 1.0;

    void SetValue(double value) { mValue = value; }
    inline double GetValue() { return mValue; }

private:
    static double mValue;
};

class Volume : public Envelope<Volume>
{
};

class Pitch : public Envelope<Pitch>
{
};

template<EnvelopeType T>
double Envelope<T>::mValue;

int main()
{
    Envelope<Volume> mVolume;
    Envelope<Pitch> mPitch;

    mVolume.SetValue(0.5);
    mPitch.SetValue(1.0);
}
```

What's wrong? It says *unknown type name "`EnvelopeType`"*. Of course it doesn't know: that's the `T` type of the template.

Comment: `template<EnvelopeType T>` what is this?

Comment: A CRTP doesn't make much sense with this regardless. Neither `Volume` nor `Pitch` are actually used *anywhere* besides as template parameter arguments. If you had `Volume mVolume;` etc. in your `main()` this would make more sense. The lack of needing those extra classes was why the [example I linked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bac589e88912052) in your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244021/which-kind-of-pattern-should-i-use-for-this-kind-of-task) (since deleted) used non-type arguments instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `template <EnvelopeType T>` then this is a template which takes one **non-type argument** `T` **of type** `EnvelopeType`. You're getting the *"unknown type"* error because there is no type called `EnvelopeType` in that context. In your code, the type `EnvelopeType` is only visible as a type in the definition of `template<class EnvelopeType> class Envelope`.

Instead, you probably meant to write this:

```
template <typename T>
double Envelope<T>::mValue;
```

Comment: Clear! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This

```
template<EnvelopeType T>
double Envelope<T>::mValue;
```

should actually look like

```
template<typename T>
double Envelope<T>::mValue;
```

since you are defining a variable inside an `Evelope` with some `T` type.