# Static variable in all children with "recursion"

Tags: c++, inheritance, recursion, static, crtp

I have something like

```
struct Base{
  int x=0;
};
```

And I want all the children to have a static variable "myint" so that, when built, they cumulate in x the values of myint for all parents and themselves. (In reality in my case x is a set and what i want is the union of the sets of each children).

```
struct Derived : public Base {
  static int myint =1;
  Derived(){x+=myint;}
};

struct Derived2 : public Derived {
  static int myint = 2;
  Derived2(){x+=myint;}
};
```

So that x=1 for Derived and x=3 for Derived2.

I've seen that something like this is possible with CRTP ([static variable for each derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796580/static-variable-for-each-derived-class)) writing a BaseX class:

```
template<class A>
struct BaseX : public Base {
  static int myint;
  BaseX() {Base::x+=myint;}
}

struct Derived : public BaseX<Derived>;
```

But such pattern can't be applied for the second level of inheritance. I tried with multiple inheritance but what I obtain, of course, is that I have two values for x, each one with the wrong value (say x=1 for the part inheriting from Derived, and x=2 for the part deriving from BaseX).

Do you see any solution for this problem without having to call for (x+=myint) in all constructor and define myint in each derived?

Comment: smells a bit like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is that `x` good for? Does really need each instance of `Derived` its own copy of it? What can you do with `x` that you cannot do already with `myint` ?

Comment: well, no. Not each instance. X can be static as well. Actually it corresponds to the set of "keywords" allowed for that particular class. Each class has its own keywords, plus all those of its parents.

Comment: The methods in Base check if the keywords are allowed and just save the value provided.

Comment: Also I just want to add that it will rarely occurs to have multiple instances of the same class

Answer (score 2):

Variation for not-int/enum types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Base {
    std::set<std::string> x;
};

template <class BASE>
struct Derived : BASE {
    static const std::string my_str;
    Derived() {
        this->x.insert(my_str);
    }
};

struct Derived1 : Derived<Base> {};
template<>
const std::string Derived<Base>::my_str = "derived";

struct Derived2 : Derived<Derived1> {};
template<>
const std::string Derived<Derived1>::my_str = "derived2";

int main() {
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;

    for (const auto & word : d1.x) {
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }

    for (const auto & word : d2.x) {
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like a pain in the ** in saying this but in this solution I believe all derived share the same static variable. Suppose to write   struct Derived1B : public Derived<Base>; There's no way to specialize Derived1::...::my_str="Derived" and Derived1B::...::my_str="DerivedB"

Comment: very good idea. Probably it can be generalized with some helper structure. I'll give it a try. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int x = 0;
};

template <class BASE, int MY>
struct Derived : BASE {
    static const int myint = MY;
    Derived() {
        this->x += myint;
    }
};

struct Derived1 : Derived<Base, 1> {};
struct Derived2 : Derived<Derived1, 2> {};

int main() {
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    std::cout << d1.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << d2.x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: well, in the case of int it is indeed a good solution. However, the actual type of "x" is a std::set and, AFAIK, there's no way to pass particular instances of a type other than enum and int as template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have to thank Toxa Evtushenko for the help. Thanks to his idea I came up with this variation which I believe can be applied in a general way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Base {
  std::set<std::string> x;
};

template<class DERIVED>
struct help{
  static const std::string my_str;
};

template <class BASE, class DERIVED>
struct Derived : BASE {
private:
  help<DERIVED> val;
public:
  Derived() {
    this->x.insert(val.my_str);
  }
};

struct Derived1a;
template<> const std::string help<Derived1a>::my_str = "Derived1A";

struct Derived1a : Derived<Base,Derived1a> {};

struct Derived1b;
template<> const std::string help<Derived1b>::my_str = "Derived1B";

struct Derived1b : Derived<Base,Derived1b> {};

struct Derived2;
template<> const std::string help<Derived2>::my_str = "Derived2";
struct Derived2 : Derived<Derived1a,Derived2> {};

int main() {
  Derived1a d1a;
  Derived1b d1b;
  Derived2  d2;

  for (const auto & word : d1a.x) {
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (const auto & word : d1b.x) {
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (const auto & word : d2.x) {
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Of course more elegant solutions are welcome!